# Infinite module with finite quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm looking for examples of an infinite ring $R$ and infinite $R$-module $M$ that has a proper submodule $N$ such $M/N$ is finite?

Answer (score 3):

The ring $\Bbb{Z}$ is infinite and $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ is finite (where I see $\Bbb{Z}$ and  $n\Bbb{Z}$ as $\Bbb{Z}$-modules).

Answer (score 1):

Take a finite family of ideals $(a_i)$ in $\Bbb Z$ then 
$$\Bbb Z/(a_1)\oplus...\oplus\Bbb Z/(a_n)$$
is a pretty one.

Comment: if the $a_i$ are pairwise coprime then $\bigoplus_s\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z_{a_s}\cong{\Bbb Z}/\bigcap_s(a_s)$

Comment: it means that the map  $\Bbb Z\to\bigoplus_s{\Bbb Z}/(a_s)$ via $x\mapsto(\overline{x},...,\overline{x})$ is epimorphism. This result is a.k.a the Chinese Remainder Thm.

Answer (score 1):

Quotients of $\Bbb Z$ as in Nitrogens solution provide a beautiful and simple example, but it is a little special that nontrivial quotients of $\Bbb Z$ are all finite. Here's a more general strategy:

If you have any infinite ring $R$, and an $R$ module $M'$ that is finite, then it is easy to build $M=M'\times R$ which is infinite, and furthermore $N=\{0\}\times R$ allows you to conclude $M/N\cong M'$, which is finite.

What I'm getting at is that you can always recover a piece of a direct sum by a quotient, so it is sometimes possible to build a counterexample this way, depending on the properties you're looking for.